# Is there a way to get the modern app launchers on xfce?

Tags: xfce

I am tired of searching for a way to open apps like it is in windows or other DEs like cinnamon where you click the app launcher and it opens with leaving a indicator on the app launcher.
However in xfce it is totally different the best setup I could do was adding the app launcher and window buttons but its still not what I want this is what my current setup works like:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

### I found the solution

here is a plugin for xfce panel: https://github.com/nsz32/docklike-plugin 
 Install it then go panel preferences > Items > Add > Choose Docklike taskbar and its done!